# Run exe on the server side with node.js

Tags: c++, node.js, exe, server

I have some C++ code compiled to an .exe file. The .exe takes some input and gives an output.

Has anyone experience on the field? What are some suggested ways that I can accomplish such a result? What module is suggested?

Comment: I don't really get what the question is....

Comment: I want to run an executable( .exe file ) using node. Calling it from my app.js file. Calling it from the backend.